# Firefox reset automatically in startup 15.10

Tags: firefox, 15.10, reset

My Firefox reset after shutdown. Firefox profile is copied to a backup one and Firefox starting a new one.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 teddy teddy  104 Mar 19 13:12 profiles.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 teddy teddy   39 Mar 19 13:29 s0de74ws.default -> /run/shm/teddy-firefox-s0de74ws.default/
drwx------ 3 teddy teddy 4096 Mar 19 13:27 s0de74ws.default-backup/
```

This started after the upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10. I'm having the same issue in Google Chrome and Chromium.

Is it a bug?